# Web.py trouble using JS file

Tags: javascript, python, web.py

I am following a tutorial for the web.py framework, and I am basically setting up the framework for a blog. However, when I implement the registration form, I use a js file that was provided to me by the teacher of the online class. It is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("loaded");
$.material.init();

$(document).on("submit", "#register-form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
    var form = $('#register-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/postregistration'
        type: 'POST'
        data: form
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Inside of the HTML file, I define it as follows, along with the rest of my js files:

```
$var js: static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js static/js/bootstrap.min.js static/js/material.min.js static/js/ripples.min.js static/js/scripty.js
```

scripty.js is located in static/js, so I believe my syntax is all right, however I do not get any feedback from the console in Chrome when I access the website through localhost. This is a problem since I want to use AJAX to get the information, but I can't tell if the js is working. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$var js` simply defines a parameter named `js`. It doesn't actually tell the browser to load javascript -- in fact, by itself, it doesn't tell the browser anything.

You'll need to write the appropriate HTML in your template:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery...."></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootst...."></script>
```

etc.

If you want to utilize your `$js`, you could have your template write the loads for you:

```
$if content.get('js', None):
    $for x in content.js.split(' '):
        <script src="/$x"></script>
```